# Showers at Bali DPS airport, international departure terminal?

Tags: airports, bali

Are there free/cheap shower facilities at Bali Ngurah Rai (Denpasar) airport's international departure terminal? The [official website](https://www.bali-airport.com) doesn't mention any, other websites mention only lounges which cost ~$35+ per person. Some individual traveller's blogs mention free showers hidden behind the toilets, but it's unclear how current this information is.

Can somebody confirm which of these facts are true?

Since our flight leaves at midnight and we'll be sweating the entire day before, it'd be nice to have a quick shower before takeoff without going broke.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can confirm that the showers which [seem to have existed at some point](https://tabigogo.com/airportshawer/) appear to have been removed. As far as I could find, there are no free shower facilities in the departure area. There is however a spa just before the gate area, and of course the lounges.

As a slightly hidden goodie: there's an unmarked roomy rest area with change rooms right at the start of the departure terminal, before pre-check-in-security, behind the toilets. Easy to overlook, but very good for rearranging your luggage and changing of clothes.

Answer (score 3):

The Premier Lounge has showers, access costs ~20 bucks, not very expensive. I believe that's the only one with showers.

Garuda's lounge is... underwhelming, and access is limited to Business/First class traveling with them, plus SkyTeam elite.

Comment: But are there showers outside of the lounges, as was asked in the question?

Comment: The question is "Can somebody confirm which of these facts are true?" I answered to the best of my knowledge: fact #2 is indeed true.